# JsonObject getString with new line

Tags: php, android, json

So, one question:

Lets say that I want to make a text view like this:

tv1
tv2
**tv7**

from a jsonarray like this

```
[{
        "value1": "tv1",
        "value2": "tv2",
        "value3": "",
        "value4": "",
        "value5": "",
        "value6": "",
        "value7": "tv7"
}]
```

How can I write this line? `tv1+"\n"+tv2+"\n"+""+""+""+""+""+tv7+"\n";`

Comment: What is you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Parse the json array into a ArrayList and then when you create your textview string do this:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

```
String mytext;
for(int i = 0; i < myarray.size; i++){
if(myarray.get(i).lenght > 1)
   mytext += myarray.get(i) + " \n ";
}
```

I have used this before so i know that it's a viable solution with minimal performance decreases.